# How to let the user choose what file to open?

Tags: c++

I have created a program that has three separate text files all with different values inside, I want to ask the user and let them choose which text file they want to use. After this it calculates the average and sum on the numbers which I have already coded.

How can I go about letting the user select which .txt file to use?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;

    double sum = 0,
        total = 0,
        average,
        number;

    inputFile.open("1nums.txt");

    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error opening the file." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (inputFile >> number)
        {
            sum += number;
            total++;
        }
        average = sum / total;

        cout << "Sum  : " << sum << endl;
        cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
        cout << "Average: " << average << endl;

    }
    inputFile.close();
    cout << "File closed. Program Ended." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code only opens one file. To more directly answer your question would require more information. If you're hard-coding stuff, just present a menu and the user makes a numerical selection. If you want to get fancy with it you can use `<filesystem>`.

Answer (score 0):

Before opening the file, prompt the user then read the response. Something like

```
string filename;
cout << "What file would you like to open? ";
cin >> filename;

inputFile.open(filename);
```